# remove all non word characters from the string

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove all the non word characters from a string, but want to keep the space.
Example:

```
    String a = "Graeme O'Connor Dasha Nicholls  Claire N MacDermott1 • Julia K Catherine Bryant1 Josèô Gil2";
    String b = a.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]+", " ");
    System.out.println("replaced: " + b);
```

Expected output:

> Graeme O'Connor Claire N MacDermott Julia K Catherine Bryant Josèô Gil

But I am getting

> Graeme O Connor Claire N MacDermott Julia K Catherine Bryant Josèô Gil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    String a = "Graeme O'Connor Dasha Nicholls  Claire N MacDermott1 • Julia K Catherine Bryant1 Josèô Gil2";
    String b = a.replaceAll(".*?(\\b[\\p{L}']+)[^\\p{L}']*", "$1 ");
    System.out.println("replaced: " + b);
```

Prints:

```
replaced: Graeme O'Connor Dasha Nicholls Claire N MacDermott Julia K Catherine Bryant Josèô Gil
```

Comment: Thanks, i have edited the questions, can you take a look at it.

Comment: @user1631306 hmm that's some chameleon question :) Ok, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Replace non-word and non-space and non`'` character then compress multiple whitespaces to one:

```
String b = a.replaceAll("[^[\\p{L}\\s']]+", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

output:

```
replaced: Graeme O'Connor Dasha Nicholls Claire N MacDermott Julia K Catherine Bryant Josèô Gil
```

Comment: Thanks, i have edited the questions, can you take a look at it.